# inserting google adwords tag in react js

Tags: reactjs, events, google-ads-api

I want to insert the google tag in my react website. but my problem is with the event tracking (for lead).

I have put the global tag in the index.html no problem. but I want to trigger the event gtag_report_conversion from a component when the user submits the form.

it gives me gtag is not defined.

I found and used a package for facebook pixel but I can't seem to find something similar for Google AdWords.

here is the global tag

```
<script>
function gtag_report_conversion(url) {
  var callback = function () {
    if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
      window.location = url;
    }
  };
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'AW-881122469/KLwdCPnZ_H4QpbmTpAM',
      'event_callback': callback
  });
  return false;
}
</script>
```

then I should call this gtag_report_conversion on submit. but how can i define gtag.

I'm sure the answer is really simple but i am missing something obvious.

Comment: Did you get this to work - I am facing the same challenge?

Comment: Would you mind sharing what's the package you found for facebook pixels? I'm having the same problem-- need to install pixel for specific events.

Comment: @NatashaC https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-facebook-pixel also incase anyone needs to know.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the global tag.   Just peaked in an AdWords account and it looks more like

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google AdWords: 123456789 -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-123456789"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'AW-123456789');
</script>
```

Once you have placed the global tag you shouldn't be running into a gtag not defined message.

Comment: I have this in my index.html, but I still get `gtag is not defined` error when I `yarn start`

Comment: FWIW to get a call to gtag working I had to call `window.gtag(...)`